# Top and Bottom v-align in same container

Tags: css, responsive-design

I have the following HTML & CSS

```
<div class="menus">
    <a href="#">A</a>
    <a href="#">B</a>
    <a href="#">C</a>
    <a href="#">D</a>
    <a href="#">E</a>
    <a href="#">F</a>
</div>
```

```css
.menus a
{
    height: 2em;
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    width: 4em;
    margin: 0.3em;
}
```

I'm trying to have the three first links at the top, and the last three at the bottom of the "menus" container, like so :

[image]

following the answer at [HTML: Top and Bottom v-align in same container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9728159/html-top-and-bottom-v-align-in-same-container), I tried putting the first three and last three into their own containers, but then they lose their width

```css
header .menus .firstThree
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}

header .menus .lastThree
{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

[image]

I even tried using :nth-child, but then they're all stacked on top of each other :(

```css
header .menus a:nth-child(1),
header .menus a:nth-child(2),
header .menus a:nth-child(3)
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}
```

I need something like an absolute vertical position, but a relative horizontal one.. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work with :

```
header .menus a:nth-child(1),
header .menus a:nth-child(2),
header .menus a:nth-child(3)
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}

header .menus a:nth-child(2)
{
    margin-left: ...
}

header .menus a:nth-child(3)
{
    margin-left: ...
}

header .menus a:nth-child(4),
header .menus a:nth-child(5),
header .menus a:nth-child(6)
{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}

header .menus a:nth-child(5)
{
    margin-left: ...
}

header .menus a:nth-child(6)
{
    margin-left: ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the ul and li elements within the menu div, then set the div's height and width using css and then use the position relative to li.

Remember if you are using position absolute then you will set style to every element.

Thanks,

Shah Rukh